# Post thumbnail appear after second attempt to share on facebook

Tags: facebook, share

i recently bought a script from someone on the internet. However now i am facing a problem with my script.A visitor can make quizzes on my site (like nametests.com) and then can share the test result in his/her timeline. The problem is that the image thumbnail is not shown!
See here the screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IulZb.jpg because i cannot post images in here.

But when the user clicks close the share window above and clicks again share,after two attempts then the thumbnail is shown correctly as it should be. Can anybody help me of what the problem might be ?
The person who sold me the script now doesn't respond to me anymore.
my site url is http://www.nametest.club ,please take a look!
Thank you (i can paste you some code if you need)

Comment: Sounds like you should ask the person you bought the script from

Comment: he does not respond any more